# Git clone got stuck

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

after using git for a while already, today I got stuck:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ashishpawar517/AutoCompiler
Cloning into 'AutoCompiler'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 351, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (170/170), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
Receiving objects:  86% (302/3remote: Total 351 (delta 42), reused 149 (delta 31), pack-reused 181
Receiving objects: 100% (351/351), 1.29 MiB | 1.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (139/139), done.

$ git checkout new_update
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/foo/gitfolder/__testbase/.git/

$ git checkout new_update
error: pathspec 'new_update' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cloning into 'AutoCompiler'

you cloned into "AutoCompiler" directory. You need to change into that one after cloning:

```
cd AutoCompiler
```

then you can do `git checkout new_update`.